# How to effectively kill a frozen subprocess in Python?

Tags: python, shell, video, ffmpeg

I am dealing with a rather odd issue.

I've written a Python wrapper (in Python 2.6.6) for a year old version of ffmpeg. The problem is that given a very particular video, `ffmpeg` stops working normally (clunky output, full cpu usage, no end stage etc) and takes the python interpreter down with it.

Now, if I run `ffmpeg` with my encoding options directly from a terminal and the problematic video as input, `ffmpeg` won't immediately respond to `Ctrl-c`. I'll have to wait for a hefty of 10 seconds or more before it exits and gives me back the prompt. However if I use a 'healthy' video instead, it will simply print `Received signal 2: terminating.` and gracefully exit.

In the python wrapper I use `p.kill()` to no effect. The behavior is exactly the same a.k.a I have to wait 10 sec before the program exits. How can I immediately stop `ffmpeg` when it freezes with some problematic video?

Note that if I do a double `Ctrl-c` I get the prompt back immediately no matter what.

Comment: Process groups are very handy for this; `os.killpg(p.pid, signal.SIGTERM)`

Comment: Just tried it but unfortunately got the same result.. ffmpeg didn't immediately quit..

Comment: What about `signal.SIGKILL`?

Comment: That's very odd indeed. You might want to spawn a separate deamon-process from the initial point when your application starts, that keeps watch over the spawned processes. If the application itself fails to assess it's situation it can probably only be solved by an observing daemon. Please let us know if you find something working, I'm very curious for the solution :)

Comment: @kroolik Good point. `SIGTERM` might fail when process turn zombie or anything else relating to idle statuses.

Comment: @Allendar, or simply when the subprocess decides to block `SIGTERM`, or registers custom handler that fails for some reason. ;)

Comment: I never tried this in Python, but I wonder if you can do something in the process itself to spawn a crash-destructor. So it will even try to execute a separated command, even if the normal destructor (process hangs) would trigger. Guess even that still requires an off-spawned process :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How are you executing the FFmpeg subprocess? There are lots of ways to launch and monitor processes in Python.

I used to deal with this exact problem because I used to run continuous automated testing for the FFmpeg project. When I needed to debug this, I would print out the PID that my program *thinks* corresponds to the running FFmpeg process. Then I would use `top` or `ps` to verify that the PID was correct. There was some weirdness between Linux and Mac OS X concerning shell parameters passed to the Python function and whether the PID correlated to the FFmpeg process or to the shell that launched the FFmpeg process.

See also: [this old blog post I wrote exploring the problem, and the numerous responses](http://multimedia.cx/eggs/process-of-confusion/).

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the problem. Well spotted! I was killing the containing shell and not the actual process..! However, why is that happening??

Comment: "shell=True" instructs the function to open a shell and run the command in the Popen case. That's where the extra shell comes from. To get around that, I seem to recall it was necessary to pass "shell=False" and then pass a list of words that comprise the command rather than a string containing the entire command.

Comment: Makes sense... however in my code I don't use 'shell=True' at all and instead pass a specific list of parameters as you said.. So, where does that extra shell come from?

Comment: I have no idea-- you never actually mentioned how you were spawning the FFmpeg process. subprocess module? What statement?

Answer (score 1):

if you are using linux you may leave it to the shell by:

```
subprocess.call( "kill -9 $(pidof ffmpeg)", shell=True )
```

Comment: I work with different Linux systems as well as OSX. This is very unreliable cross-platform. I'm not saying it's wrong tho. I used this code before on specific *nix systems. I think it's better to let the code itself remember the situation. You could also bind a destructor to the process itself and let it kill all it's subprocess which might comply to certain rules.